# Dictionary of Geolocations

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geocoding

I have written a code in order to get a dictionary which shows me museum as key and geolocation information as values. The museum is always taken from a list of museums (df2). I get almost the result I want. However, unfortunately, the returned dictionary always holds the same coordinates. Hence, the values are not updated respective to the key .

Would love to get some help with that!

```
def geocode(museum):
    location = geolocator.geocode(museum, exactly_one = False)
    return location

d = {}
for museum in df2:
    if geocode(museum) is False:
        d[museum] = 'Nothing found'
    else: 
        d[museum] = [location[0].latitude],[location[0].longitude], [len(location)]
```

Comment: You should store the return of the `geocode` function and then use it to assign it, i.e. `location` should be updated based on your call to `geocode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the return of the `geocode` function and then use it to assign it, i.e. location should be updated based on your call to `geocode`.

Try modifying when you build your dictionary as follows:

```
for museum in df2:
    loc = geocode(museum)
    if loc is None:
        d[museum] = 'Nothing found'
    else: 
        d[museum] = [loc[0].latitude],[loc[0].longitude], [len(loc)]
```

Comment: @PCUnique could you post the traceback of the error? As I don't have the data for the geolocator I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Can you try changing `if loc is False:` to `if loc is None:`?